# How to add a check box that can be toggled on and off for "Always on top" or "Top most"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am working on a project in visual studio, and I need help with a check box that when clicked the window would always be on top, and when turned off then it will no longer be on top.

I have already added it for when it is toggled on but I don't know how to toggle it to turn off.

this.TopMost = true;

The output will make the application top most but when unticked it stays on top most.

Comment: Have you simply tried `this.TopMost = <yourcheckbox>.Checked;`?

Answer (score 1):

Your basic complaint is that "the first time we click the box, the form does become TopMost, but then it stays TopMost all the time and doesn't turn off"

This is because you set TopMost = true:

```
this.TopMost = true;
```

But you didn't say you'd ever provided a way to set it false again

You could do this:

```
if(topmostCheckbox.Checked)
  this.TopMost = true;
else
  this.TopMost = false; //provide a way to turn it off
```

This is of course, more simply written as:

```
this.TopMost = topmostCheckbox.Checked;
```

If you're using a button to toggle it on and off, a neat trick to toggle a boolean is:

```
this.TopMost = !this.TopMost;
```

Every time this code runs it will toggle the boolean between false/true/false/true. If this code was in a button click handler, then every time the button was clicked, the "Always On Top"ness would change between on and off

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
TopMost = checkBox1.Checked
```

and it worked for me!